# adding a css file to my plugin

Tags: plugins, css

i'm new to wordpress and trying to find out how i can add a css file to plugin.

I have created a plugin called my-plugin and wrote the following into my-plugin.php:

```
<?php

/*
Plugin Name: my Plugin
Description: some description
Version: 1.0
Author: Ginso
*/



add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'callback_for_setting_up_scripts');
function callback_for_setting_up_scripts() {
    wp_register_style( 'mein-plugin', 'localhost/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/mein-plugin/style.css' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'mein-plugin' );
}



function cssTest() {
    return '<p class="myClass">some text</p>'; 
}

add_shortcode("test", "cssTest");   

?>
```

and this is currently my style.css:

```
.myClass{
    color:red;
}
```

now i added `[test]` to a page and it displays the correct text, but it doesnt apply the style. What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Have you viewed the source to see whether the CSS file is actually getting called? Have you tried inspecting the element to see if perhaps one of the theme styles is overriding it? Some themes may have more specific styles, i.e. if the theme has a style like `main.themeClass p` it would override `.myClass` because it has higher specificity.

Comment: i am not sure what u mean with your first question. When i inspect the paragraph, my style doesn't appear. if it was overridden, it would still appear  there

Answer (score 2):

Don't put the full path to the file in `wp_register_style()` use [`plugins_url()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/plugins_url) to get the full url with just the path from the plugins folder.

So change:

```
'localhost/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/mein-plugin/style.css'
```

To:

```
plugins_url( 'style.css', __FILE__ )
```